# Exclude methods from delombok for Javadoc purposes

Tags: maven, lombok

I am working on documentation using the Maven Javadoc plugin, including a `delombok` phase to document getters and setters, then push to `gh-pages`.  However, this pulls in other lombok generated methods such as `equals`.  Is there a way to specify only a subset of methods to be documented after `delombok`ing?

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
            <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>format</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.12.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0-beta4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>delombok</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>delombok</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <bottom>Copyright &#169; {currentYear}. All rights reserved.</bottom>
                <show>public</show>
                <sourcepath>module-a/target/delombok;
                            module-b/target/delombok;</sourcepath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-publish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <checkoutDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scmpublish</checkoutDirectory>
                <checkinComment>Publishing javadoc for ${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</checkinComment>
                <content>${project.javadoc.directory}</content>
                <skipDeletedFiles>true</skipDeletedFiles>
                <pubScmUrl>scm:git:git@github.com:MyNamespace/MyProject.git</pubScmUrl>
                <scmBranch>gh-pages</scmBranch>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Is there a problem that equals and hashcode (and possibly canEqual) are in the documentation?